# How hibernate ensures second level cache is updated with latest data in database

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache

I have read that using hibernate's second level cache, it can improve applications performance by having less database hits for data / object retrieval.

However, how does hibernate ensure that second level cache is up to date with the data in database.

For, example:

Suppose the below class is entity and persisted into the DB.

```
@Entity
class User {
    Id
    private int id;
    private String str;
}
```

Now, if we have enabled second level cache, I understand that if we open different sessions then each session will hit the second level cache for retrieving object value.

Now, if data in database gets changes (for e.g. for row with id=1) say by some independent process/ manually changing the values, and we try to access the value, how does hibernate detect that the cache is having latest value (for id = 1).

In general, how does hibernate ensure that data in second level cache is consistent with the db values.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hibernate manages the cache himself, so when you **update** some entity thru hibernate Session it will **invalidate** cache entry assocciated with this entity - so cache is always fresh.

If another process (or even second JVM running the same hibernate application) updates record in database, Hibernate on first JVM is unaware of this fact and has **stale** object in his cache.

However you can use any cache implementation (cache provider) you want. There are many production-ready cache providers that allow you to configure how long given entity will be stored in cache. For example you can configure your cache to invalide all entities after 30 seconds and so on.

If you use EhCache cache provider you can provide such configuration:

```
<cache name="com.my.company.Entity" 
   maxElementsInMemory="1000" 
   eternal="false" 
   timeToIdleSeconds="7200" 
   timeToLiveSeconds="7200" 
   overflowToDisk="false" 
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

You can find more information abount L2 cache here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm

however there is a lot of useful tutorials about this.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed info. So, can we treat this as one of the disadvantages of using the hibernate? Are there any remedies for this?

Comment: This is not so much about hibernate, but it is a principle problem with caches. As we all know there are 10 problems in IT: naming things and cache invalidation and of by one errors

Comment: @Jens Yes, naming things is probably the worst :)

Comment: @vipin Caching stratety should depend on project specific demands. For example for some project if table isn't updated too often - you can cache entities for this table with timeToLive=10 minutes, but for tables that are often updated you can set timeToLive=10 seconds or just do not cache them

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't.

If you change data in the database without using hibernate it won't know about it and your cache and the database get out of sync.

Comment: If some component within the same application changes the values (using hibernate) how does it keep track of the changes?