# what is the impact of a jdbc query on hibernate second level cache? Can I trigger the cache refresh for a specific cache region

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jdbc, second-level-cache

I have a jdbc update query which updates a table. And entity cache is maintained for the same table in hibernate. I need to tell hibernate to refresh the cache region for that entity which is updated by the jdbc query.

Comment: This should help you [How hibernate ensures second level cache is updated with latest data in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413321/how-hibernate-ensures-second-level-cache-is-updated-with-latest-data-in-database)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
sessionFactory.getCache().evictEntityRegion(MyEntity.class)
```

This removes the stale entries from cache. However, if you do that before JDBC update, in the window between this invalidation and the JDBC update, the cache can be populated again by concurrent reads, so if your application does not stop all DB accesses, you could end up with some stale entries.

Another region eviction after the update could sort it out, but between the JDBC query and region eviction you're prone to inconsistent data in the cache, again.